# Problem with ngRepeat inside ngRepeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an issue with ngRepeat that I just can't seem to solve. You can see the issue here: https://codepen.io/markbernard/pen/ExWvJLe.

The relevant area looks like this code starting on line 59:

```
<div style="border:2px dashed #8f8" ng-repeat="(indexl1, sectionLevel1NavigationItem) in leftNavSectionItem.sectionLevel1Navigation">
    <h4><span data-i18n="common.sectionl1navigation">Section Level 1 Navigation</span> - {{indexl1 + 1}}</h4>
    <div>Acronym level 1 = {{sectionLevel1NavigationItem.acronymOnly}}</div>
    <div> <!-- acronym -->
        <fieldset>
            <legend data-i18n="common.displayAcronym">Display Only Acronym</legend>
            <label><input type="radio" name="acronymOnly{{index}}{{indexl1}}" value="y" ng-model="sectionLevel1NavigationItem.acronymOnly" /><span data-i18n="common.yes">Yes</span></label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="acronymOnly{{index}}{{indexl1}}" value="n" ng-model="sectionLevel1NavigationItem.acronymOnly" /><span data-i18n="common.no">No</span></label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

There are 3 levels: Section Navigation, Section Level 1 Navigation and Section Level 2 Navigation. Level 2 only appears inside level 1 and level 1 only appears inside the Section Navigation. The issue only appears in the Level 1 Navigation on the acronym radio button. It does not properly set up the bind. Neither Yes nor No are selected, even though there is a value in the bound variable. You can see it visually. I added some plain text showing the value right above it. Also if you click the Yes or No radio button you can see the value change in the text portion, so it is properly bound. It is doubly weird since the other bound values in the same level work fine.

I even tried a hack to find all the acronym elements, after render, and set them based on the appropriate bound value. That didn't work either.

I have rewritten it twice to try to see if I am making a mistake. Searching turns up nothing.

Can anyone see if I am missing something? Or is this some obscure bug?

The best spot to see it is "**Section Navigation - 2**". The first level 1 has a level 2 below it. The level 1 acronym does not work but the level 2 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a clean solution. The only thing I could do was to find all the acronymOnly radio buttons, after render, and set the appropriate one to checked in Javascript. The first time I tried to do this I must have made a mistake. The last time I tried I got it to work.